# Image preview with Symfony 4 and SonataAdmin

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin

I want to show an uploaded image preview on my sonata form. The image is related to an other entity.

I've succeeded to upload the image and to get his filename in the view list. But now I would like to have a preview of that image shown as well in the list view and in the form view.

This is what I have (simplified version)

ForumAdmin with the file upload system

```
class ForumAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('name', TextType::class);
        $formMapper->add('description', TextAreaType::class);
        $formMapper->add('weight', IntegerType::class);
        $formMapper->add('category', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Category::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ]);
        $formMapper->add('file', FileType::class, array('required' => false));
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add('name');
        $datagridMapper->add('category');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('imageName');
    }


  public function preUpdate($forum){
    $this->saveFile($forum);
  }

  public function saveFile($forum) {
    $basepath = $this->getRequest()->getBasePath();
    $forum->upload($basepath);
  }

}
```

ImageAdmin

```
final class ImageAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('image', FileType::class);
    }

    public function prePersist($image)
    {
        $this->manageFileUpload($image);
    }

    public function preUpdate($image)
    {
        $this->manageFileUpload($image);
    }

    private function manageFileUpload($image)
    {
        if ($image->getFile()) {
            $image->refreshUpdated();
        }
    }
}
```

I was searching about may be trying to override sonata template, but I don't think this is how to do. I also have been reading the documentation [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/cookbook/recipe_image_previews.html) but either I don't understand either I can't make it work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you have already found that tutorial, what keeps you from implementing it? The basic example shows how to add the needed markup

Comment: @NicoHaase As I said, I already tried to follow that tutorial and it wasn't working. I had no error, the file still uploaded but still no preview in the form view.

Comment: Can you share your attempts? The code in the tutorial does not look like the one you've added to the question

Comment: @NicoHaase It's the same, I just tried to copy paste their `configureFormFields` from 5.2.2 into mine. I can add it to the issue in case the link comes to be broken some day. But the attempt is the same